# Is it ok to typecast an argument to std::min()?

Tags: c++

I just got a compiler error for the following construct:

```
size_t N = 10;
size_t Ntransforms = std::min(PySequence_Fast_GET_SIZE(__transforms), N);
```

since `PySequence_Fast_GET_SIZE()` actually returns `Py_ssize_t` and `std::min()` is defined as

```
template <class T> const T& min (const T& a, const T& b);
```

Since it takes lvalue references of the same type, I was surprised that I could fix it with an inline typecast:

```
size_t Ntransforms = std::min((size_t)PySequence_Fast_GET_SIZE(__transforms), N);
```

Is this OK? If yes, is it equivalent to the explicit code:

```
size_t Ntransforms = PySequence_Fast_GET_SIZE(__transforms);
if (Ntransforms > N) Ntransforms = N;
```

Comment: Assuming `PySequence_Fast_GET_SIZE` does not ever return a negative value sure, you can also provide an explicit template type instead i.e. `std::min<size_t>` and rely on the implicit conversion. While it won't make any difference here you might want to avoid using c-style casts, it's good to get into the habit of using `static_cast` instead.

Comment: `min` takes `const lvalue references`, hence they bind to temporaries

Comment: Weird Naming Convention : `PySequence_Fast_GET_SIZE`.

Comment: Yes @PiotrS., forgot about that!

Comment: @Nawaz Of course it's weird, it's Python ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `std::min` signature forces the same type of arguments:

```
 template <class T> const T& min (const T& a, const T& b);
```

The call is ambiguous in case the types of arguments differ.

However, it is fine to use temporaries (resulting e.g. from a cast expression) in place of arguments, because `std::min` takes `const` lvalue references.

Alternatively, you can force the type used to instantiate `std::min`:

```
std::min<std::size_t>(PySequence_Fast_GET_SIZE(__transforms), N);
```

Comment: Thanks! I particularly like the type-forcing version that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Yet it is equivalent to the variant you specified. You are free to use the form:

```
size_t Ntransforms = std::min(static_cast<size_t>(PySequence_Fast_GET_SIZE(__transforms)), N);
```